# Apache Location precedence with mod_wl_ohs.so

Tags: apache-2.2, weblogic

I'm running Oracle HTTP Server with mod_wl_ohs enabled.

I have the following config:

```
# Applications
<Location />
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster mt2:7003,mt3:7003
</Location>

# Admin Server and EM
<Location /console>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost mt1
    WeblogicPort 7001
</Location>

<Location /consolehelp>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost mt1
    WeblogicPort 7001
</Location>

<Location /em>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicHost mt1
    WeblogicPort 7001
</Location>
```

I want all requests to go to the (mt2, mt3) cluster except those for /console /consolehelp and /em which should go to mt1.

Using the above config the /console /consolehelp and /em give 404s. Going to the server directly does work though. Any URI on going to the cluster on / works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apache config files are parsed top to bottom, so I would expect the root location handler is being applied to your requests before the other location handlers are reached. Try putting the root location handler last.

Have you checked the logs to see what is happening? You may need to turn on debug, or a high-level trace LogLevel. [Here's the list of available log levels.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel)

Answer (score -1):

Replace mt# with your actual server names